# Is it possible to get Facebook checkins of a user using an Facebook app?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to build a an app that gets user's Facebook checkins. Is it still possible to get checkin data from Facebook API. I did some research and learned it might not be possible anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following endpoint: `/me/tagged_places`. You will need the `user_tagged_places` permission.

Check out the [documentation here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/tagged_places/).